# SQL query select results dependent on two values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a an issue where I'm running a not exists query in my database

```
Description       SUBMITTER
---------------------------
General worklog   U1
Scope             U1
Email-Out         U2
General worklog   U3
planning          U3
```

My query is:

```
SELECT chg.CHANGE_ID,
chg.USER
FROM dbc as chg
WHERE chg.USER in ('U1')
 and NOT EXISTS (SELECT logs.Description 
    from db as logs 
    WHERE 
       logs.CHANGE_ID = chg.CHANGE_ID 
       and 
       (
     (logs.DESCRIPTION LIKE 'Email-O%'
      and 
      logs.SUBMITTER in ('U1','U3')) 
      or 
      logs.DESCRIPTION like 'Scope'
    ))
```

What I'm trying to do is find instances where there been no "Email-O" by U1 or U3 or there's no Description of Scope.

With the query I'm running I'm getting results with no Email-O but it's dropping the result if there's another entry by U1 or U3.

Effectively, I'm trying to explicitly tie the Email-O to any number of users but for some reason it's not working as expected.

Appreciate the help?

---

In terms of my output based on the updated query

If I select `logs.SUBMITTER in ('U1','U3')` I'm returning fewer values than if I select `logs.SUBMITTER in ('U1')`. I believe this is because the logs.SUBMITTER value isn't explicitly tied to the logs.DESCRIPTION value of 'Email-O' so as U3 has entered a value of 'planning' this is dropping a result.

Comment: Can you show the expected output here?

Comment: I think there's an error in your query possibly after the `in` - the brackets don't match

Comment: You don't provide logs.CHANGE_ID.  How can you expect help if you don't provide necessary information?   Provide data and desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem looks like missing brackets, try this.

```
SELECT *
FROM dbc as chg
WHERE chg.USER in ('U1','U3')
 and NOT EXISTS (SELECT logs.Description 
    from db as logs 
    WHERE 
       logs.CHANGE_ID = chg.CHANGE_ID 
       and (
        ( ( logs.DESCRIPTION LIKE 'Email-O%'
            and logs.SUBMITTER in ('U1','U3')) 
         or logs.DESCRIPTION like 'Scope' )
    ))
```

Comment: Thanks, I'd missed a bracket from my post but I'm still having the issue.

Comment: @nixxrite you should post about `dbc` as well in your question and also include some details about `change_id`

Answer (score 0):

```
and NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 
                   from db as logs 
                  WHERE logs.CHANGE_ID = chg.CHANGE_ID 
                    and ( ( logs.DESCRIPTION LIKE 'Email-O%' and 
                            logs.SUBMITTER in (U1,U3)
                          ) 
                          or logs.DESCRIPTION like 'Scope'
                        )
               )
```

This is you culprit `logs.CHANGE_ID` but you don't include it in the data nor do you include `chg`

Comment: Apologies, I was in the process of adding the full query for context.